# Error 'Install-Module is not recognised.' when Linux Azure App Service tries to install PS module

Tags: linux, powershell, powershell-core

I have an ASP.NET Core web app (Linux) as an Azure App Service and a page tries to install the ExchangeOnlineManagement PowerShell module. The script needs to connect to exchange and call Get-EXOMailbox. The script reports PowerShell v7.3.6.

I get this error:
"The term 'Install-Module' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program"

```
var scriptContents = "if(-not (Get-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement -ListAvailable))" + Environment.NewLine +
                    "{ " + Environment.NewLine +
                        "Write-Host $PSVersionTable.PSVersion" + Environment.NewLine +
                        "Install-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement -Scope CurrentUser -Force" + Environment.NewLine +
                    "}";
            
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    ps.AddScript(scriptContents);
    var pipelineObjects = await ps.InvokeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Context**:

- PowerShell (Core) SDK projects built with the PowerShell [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PowerShell) - that is, applications or libraries that host their own copy of PowerShell - do *not* bundle the same non-built-in modules that stand-alone [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) installations do.

  - Notably, this means that a PowerShell SDK project does *not* come with the `PowerShellGet` module that the `Install-Module` cmdlet is a part of.
  - Specifically, an SDK project bundles only the following modules:

    - `Microsoft.PowerShell.Host`
    - `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management`
    - `Microsoft.PowerShell.Security`
    - `Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility`
- On *Windows*, where there is a predefined `PSModulePath` environment variable (`$env:PSModulePath`) that points to legacy *Windows PowerShell* (all-users only) directories even when running an executable from *outside* a PowerShell session, you should still be able to call `Install-Module`, which - in the absence of a `-Scope` argument - would result in a *user-level* installation of the targeted module.

  - Due to PowerShell itself augmenting `PSModulePath` on startup (see below), its user-level module root directory will be targeted (`$HOME\Documents\PowerShell\Modules` on Windows), which means that stand-alone PowerShell (Core) 7+ sessions will see any installed module there too. (Similarly, a `-Scope AllUsers` installation from a PowerShell (Core) SDK project would install to the all-users PowerShell (Core) 7+ location, `$env:ProgramFiles\PowerShell\Modules` on Windows.)
- On *Unix*-like platforms - such as in your case (Linux) - there is *no* predefined  `PSModulePath` environment variable, which explains your symptom.

  - While PowerShell itself (in both editions) defines `PSModulePath` with default values (also for user-specific locations) when it starts up, in SDK projects it will use the directory of the *hosting application* as the directory for its *system* modules, i.e. the ones bundled with PowerShell itself.

---

**Upshot**:

**An application / library hosting PowerShell *may* find a `PowerShellGet` module** (which hosts the `Install-Module` cmdlet) **via a preexisting *stand-alone* PowerShell installation**; the same **applies to all *system* modules**, i.e. those that come bundled with such an installation:

- ***Always* on *Windows***, given that Windows PowerShell ships with Windows.

  - If you happen to start your application from a PowerShell (Core) 7+ session, your application will use the latter's `PowerShellGet` module.
  - As an aside re *non*-system modules:

    - *If* there happens to be a stand-alone PowerShell 7+ installation, your application will also see the modules that were *installed by the user* there, typically via `Install-Module`.
- ***Only incidentally, if at all*, on *Unix***-like platforms:

  - *If* you happen to start your application from a PowerShell 7+ session (as opposed to from, say, Bash), your application will use the latter's `PowerShellGet` module.
  - Otherwise, your application won't find that module.
  - As an aside re *non*-system modules:

    - *If* there happens to be a stand-alone PowerShell 7+ installation, your application will also see the modules that were *installed by the user* there, typically via `Install-Module`.

**Caveat**:

- Even if present, use of `Install-Module` will invariably target the module directories of the stand-alone PowerShell installation that the module is "borrowed" from - which may be undesired.

---

***Custom on-demand installation of PowerShell modules* from applications hosting their own copy of PowerShell:**

Since you cannot assume the presence of the `Install-Module` cmdlet on non-Windows platforms, you'll need *custom code* to download and install modules on demand.

- While this is obviously cumbersome, it has the advantage of letting you install private copies of the modules you need, in a local directory of your choice.
- A **potential alternative** is to download the `PowerShellGet` and `PackageManagement` modules *at development time* and *bundle them with your application / library* - but this will again install to module directories that are shared with stand-alone PowerShell (Core) installations.

The following code automates the manual steps documented in [Manual Package Download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/gallery/how-to/working-with-packages/manual-download) for directly downloading and installing a module from the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/):

- Specify the full path of the local directory below in which modules downloaded on demand should be installed.
- **Limitations** of the code:

  - *Dependencies*, i.e. additional modules that your target module(s) require to function must be *explicitly* downloaded as well.
  - For simplicity, the code simply downloads the *latest stable* version of the specified (module), though adding support for versioning doesn't require much more effort.
- See the source-code comments for details.

```bash
# Make the Write-Verbose statements below produce output.
# Set to $false to silence them.
$verbose = $true

# The name(s) of the module(s) to download.
# If a module has *dependencies*, i.e. requires other modules to function,
# append them to the array.
# SEE NOTE ABOUT VERSIONS BELOW.
$requiredModules = @('ExchangeOnlineManagement')

# Where to install manually downloaded modules.
# Note: Be sure to use a FULL PATH.
$modulesRootDir = "$HOME\.MyApp\Modules"

# Add the root dir. of all manually installed modules to $env:PSModulePath,
# if necessary.
if (($env:PSModulePath -split [IO.Path]::PathSeparator) -notcontains $modulesRootDir) {
  $env:PSModulePath += [IO.Path]::PathSeparator + $modulesRootDir
}

# Determine which modules need to be dowloaded, if any.
$missingModules = 
  Compare-Object -PassThru $requiredModules @(Get-Module -ListAvailable $requiredModules | ForEach-Object Name)

# Download and install any missing modules.
foreach ($moduleName in $missingModules) {

  # Silence the progress display during download and ZIP archive extraction.
  # Note: For this to be effective for Expand-Archive, the *global* variable must be set.
  $prevProgressPreference = $global:ProgressPreference
  $global:ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

  try {
  
    # NOTE RE VERSIONING: 
    # For simplicity, this code does NOT support versioning, which means:
    #   * The *latest stable version* of each module is downloaded.
    #   * Such a version is placed directly in directory named for the module, 
    #     i.e. installation of *multiple versions*, side by side - which would
    #     require version-specific subdirs. - is *not* supported here.
    # To download a specific version, simply append /<version> to the URL below, e.g.:
    #       https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/PSReadLine/2.2.6
  
    # Derive the download URL, the local installation dir., and path of the temp. ZIP file.
    $downloadUrl = 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/{0}' -f $moduleName
    $moduleDir = Join-Path $modulesRootDir $moduleName
    $tempZipFile = Join-Path $moduleDir "$moduleName.zip"
  
    Write-Verbose -Verbose:$verbose "Downloading and installing module $moduleName to $moduleDir..."
    
    # Make sure the target directory exists.
    $null = New-Item -ErrorAction Stop -ItemType Directory -Force $moduleDir    
  
    # Download the *.nupkg file, as a *.zip file (which it technically is)
    Invoke-WebRequest -ErrorAction Stop $downloadUrl -OutFile $tempZipFile
      
    # Extract the contents of the *.zip file.
    Expand-Archive -ErrorAction Stop -Force -LiteralPath $tempZipFile -DestinationPath $moduleDir
    
    # Clean up files that aren't needed locally.
    Get-Item $moduleDir\* -Include *.zip, _rels, '`[Content_Types`].xml', *.nuspec, package |
      Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
  }
  finally {
    $global:ProgressPreference = $prevProgressPreference
  }

}

# Now you can import the modules - either explicitly, as in this example, 
# or implicitly, by module auto-loading via $env:PSModulePath
Write-Verbose -Verbose:$verbose "Importing module $($requiredModules[0])..."
Import-Module -ErrorAction Stop $requiredModules[0]
```